# Can't ping from guest CentOS 7 VM to another guest CentOS 7 VM

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, centos7, cloudstack

I have a problem with ping VM from and to another VM that run CentOS7. The hypervisor is KVM and I control all with CloudStack. The strange thing is that I can ping from and to secondary storage vm and console proxy vm (runs debian), so I think that the problem is in the configuration of CentOS.
The configuration of the network interface eth0 is like this:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth0
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BRIDGE=br0
```

and the configuration of the network interface br0 is like this:

```
DEVICE="br0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
TYPE="Bridge"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
DELAY="0"
```

I reach internet and the host, but not other guest CentOS vm. what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the kvm guests' network interfaces tied together on `br0` on the host?

Comment: no, I only have a nic , I set the br0 only on the guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Cloudstack default settings cannot permit to communicate among guest vms. For do this it needs to set up the **Ingress** and the **Egress** rules of the security group :)